# Dockerfile для статического приложения html на nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, dockerfile

Как настроить Dockerfile для простого статического веб приложения?

Есть максимально простая web страничка html + css, пробовал запустить с помощью докера на Nginx, но ничего не отображается.

Папка проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

COPY css ./css
COPY img ./img
COPY index.html ./
```

Прописываю команду **docker build -t catapp .**
После этого **docker run --rm -it -p 80:80 catapp**

Захожу на localhost:80, а там это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно копировать ваши статические файлы в `/usr/share/nginx/html`.

Например:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY css ./css
COPY img ./img
COPY index.html ./
```